# How to access dynamically created items in a repeater?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater:

```
<asp:repeater id="someID" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:hyperlink id=<%# Eval("ID")%> runat="server"></asp:hyperlink>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

I need to get reference to each hyperlink and access to the attributes of it.

On ItemDataBound, how do I go ahead and access a hyperlink whose ID is just being set? If I had a fixed ID for the hyperlink, that wouldn't be a problem. But since the I need the ID to also be assigned dynamically, I kinda got lost in finding the way..

Comment: Why you need to set it like that? What is the purpose?

Comment: @PraVn Because I want the IDs to be unique.

Comment: even if you set it static, while rendering, asp.net will generate unique ids. To get the ID back, you need to set ID as the DataKeyName of the repeater and in the ItemDataBound you can access it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access each item then you have to subscribe to OnItemDataBound Event and then find control

```
    private void rptMyTest_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            Control control = e.Item.FindControl("ID_OF_YOUR_CONTROL") as Control;
            if (control != null)
            {
                var dataItem = e.Item.DataItem as MYITEMTYPE;
                if (DateTime.Now > dataItem.DateYouNeedToCheck)
                    control.ToolTip = "from the past";

              //ALL THE MAGIC HAPPENS HERE
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.

**JUST ADDED**
just read your post again.

THE ID OF AN INSIDE REPEATER ELEMENT WILL BE SET AUTOMATICALY FOR EACH ITEM, but you need to set it upfront to some static value (in order to get the reference to it).

If you are trying to then access it using JQuery (or javascript), I would suggest not to use hard coded IDs - there are different ways to do stuff like that.

If you explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve, it will be much easier to answer your question or suggest something.

**UPDATE**
check code example above

Comment: Oh Ok, And I also just read about your update... You are correct in thinking that I will access them using jQuery. What I need is, I am basically binding records of events. If the date of the event is in the past, I want to set a title attribute to the anchor tag as: title="past".. I had enough problems trying to deal with dates in javascript returned by asp.net. So I wanted to see if there was a way doing it in codebehind..

Comment: why don't you check the date in code behind then and set ToolTip property to "past..." (tooltip is being rendered as title). You are unnecessarily overcomplicating things by trying to do this on the client side.

Comment: there should be a linkbutton or something like that